# How to put trunk into branche and completely update it?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I currently have a repositorie with the standard trunk/tags/branches structure.
The repositorie for "myApp" contains only few tags but no branches.

The v2 of myApp have been developped without performing any commit into the repositorie (big mistake i know). The changes in the code are major (almost everything has been changed / refactored).

I would like to keep the same repositorie for the 2 versions of "myApp"; so i would like to put  the current trunk in a branche (for maintenance fix , in case some people don't update to v2) and put my new version in the trunk.

How should i proceed ? (using tortoisesvn on Windows)

Is there a better solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply 'Create tag/branch' to put the trunk to a branch.

And than I'd probably replace the old sources in a trunk checkout with the new ones and commit, adding/removing files as necessary, so subversion will be able to show the changes (though it's not that big use). To replace the files, first delete all files in the checkout, but make sure to leave the .svn directories intact. Than copy in the new sources and select "commit" and mark all files, including unversioned and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, copy your trunk into a branch:

```
svn cp svn://server/dev/trunk svn://server/branches/myAppOrig -m "Branched trunk to submit myApp"
```

You can then always refer to the branch for the original.

Answer (score 1):

Select the branch/tag context menu item of the working copy of the trunk folder . This gives you a dialog on which you can configure what part to copy where. I don't know what the defaults in this dialog are, but you can change them such that the trunk is copied to a newly created folder insider `branches`. Make sure to not activate "switch working copy after copying". After you have done the copying, check in your working copy.